# Get AJAX return, concat and build an table

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm not able to assign my AJAX return as variable to concat.

Here is the code:

```
         function GetSex() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SEX/GetAllSex/',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
         }

         function GetUsers() {
             var Pistas = null;
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Users/GetAllUsers/',
                 success: function (data) {
                     console.log(data)

                 }
             });
         }
```

I want to concat the results, so that's what i'm doing:

```
var Sex = GetSex();
var Users = GetUsers();

var x = Users.concat(Sex);
```

It says that Sex and Users variable is undefined!

I don't understand.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: What do the results look like and what do you want them to look like?

Comment: Neither `GetSex()` or `GetUsers()` return a value - all they do is output the result of the ajax call to the console - replace `console.log(data);` with `return data;`

Comment: You need to assign your `sex` and `users` variables inside their respective success functions (Where you have your `console.log`s)..  You may also want to chain the functions together as they will return asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

I just didn't declare the variables before:

Final code was like:

```
var Sex;
var Users;

function GetSex() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/SEX/GetAllSex/',
            success: function (data) {
                Sex = data;
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
     }

     function GetUsers() {
         var Pistas = null;
         $.ajax({
             url: '/Users/GetAllUsers/',
             success: function (data) {
                 Users = data;
                 console.log(data)

             }
         });
     }
```

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

GetSex and GetUsers are asynchronous requisitions.
You need to chaining your requests and then assign the variables values inside of the callback functions.

```
function GetSex(successCallback) {
    $ajax({
        url: '/SEX/GetAllSex/',
        success: successCallback
    });
}

function GetUsers(successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Users/GetAllUsers/',
        success: successCallback
    });
}

function concatUsers(successCallback) {
    GetSex(function(Sex) {
        GetUsers(function(Users) {
            successCallback(Users.concat(Sex));
        }}
    });
}


var x;

concatUsers(function(data) {
    x = data;
});
```

Just be careful with [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/)